# merging two objects for sculpting

Tags: mesh, objects

I have two pretty complex objects that I want to merge into a single one so when I can use sculpting tools on it. Here's a picture of what I'm doing:

[image]

I want to merge the legs into the body.

Comment: yes you should use booleans to merge the meshes, but you should simplify them a bit before, i.e. make it lower in polygons, it will help to rework after the boolens

Answer (score 1):

You select both objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, to make them one object. But if you sculpt, you'll easily get the separate parts appear to be dividing up where they're not joined by their vertices. The best thing to do would be reduce the number of edge flows (temporarily) so you can cut an edge around the body where they meet the legs, delete the faces that are inside the legs, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them, then merge vertices so you have one continuous surface.  Hopefully you have an UN-applied smoothing modifier on which you can delete to simplify the geometry.